# Dynamically build a template parameter pack

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++14, variadic-templates

I'm trying to have my code call a method on a list of classes, and I want to be able to configure this list at compile time. To make matters more clear (I hope), this is approximately what I'm currently doing:

```
template <class...> class pack {};

class A {
public:
    static void foo() {};
};
class B {
public:
    static void foo() {};
};
class C {
public:
    static void foo() {};
};

using ClassList = pack<A, B, C>;

template<class T, class ...Remaining>
void do_something(pack<T, Remaining...>) {
  // do something with T
  T::foo();
  do_something(pack<Remaining...>());
}

void do_something(pack<>) {
  // do nothing, recursion ends
}

int main() {
  do_something(ClassList());
}
```

Basically, it calls do_something() witch each of A, B and C as template argument T.

Here's the twist: I want to be able to dynamically en- or disable A, B and C based on '#ifdef's. I could obviously use something like

```
#if defined(USE_A) && defined (USE_B) && defined (USE_C)
using ClassList = pack<A, B, C>;
#elif defined(USE_A) && defined (USE_B)
using ClassList = pack<A, B>;
…
```

but that results in 2^n statements (if n is the number of potential classes).

### My Solution Attempt

My solution attempt would be to have for each class T that I want to add to the class list an 'AddT' class that derives from pack, matches the parameter pack "inside" the pack class in its template definition, and then adds T. Something along the lines of:

```
using BaseClassList = pack<A, B>;

#ifdef USE_C

template <template <class ...Others> class oldpack>
class AddC : public pack<C, Others...> {};
using ClassesWithC = AddC<BaseClassList>; 

#else

using ClassesWithC = BaseClassList;

#endif
```

However, it looks like the 'inner' template parameter (pack) 'Others' is not accessible when defining AddC, the error I get is:

```
error: 'Others' was not declared in this scope
```

Am I doing something completely stupid here? Is there a nicer way of doing it? Or can the problem above be fixed? I'd happily use C++14 (or even C++1z, as far as it's implemented by a reasonable version of GCC and clang), if that helps in any way.

Comment: the answer is so obvious, that 3 equivalent answers were given simultaneously.

Comment: @Walter: but only one complete answer.

Comment: I have to agree with @walter - I was kind of blind.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Exploit the whitespace flexibility of C++ and check for each separately.

```
template<class, class...Ts>
using pack_helper = pack<Ts...>;

using ClassList = pack_helper<void
#ifdef USE_A
  ,A
#endif
#ifdef USE_B
  ,B
#endif
#ifdef USE_C
  ,C
#endif
>;
```

`pack_helper` drops its first type, then generates a `pack` with the rest.  We pass `void` for it.

We do this so each of the other pack elements can all *start* with a comma, including the first one.

---

But that isn't as fun as it could be.

```
template<class...>struct pack{using type=pack; constexpr pack(){}};
template<class...Ts>constexpr pack<Ts...> pack_v{};

template<class...Ts, class...Us>
constexpr pack<Ts...,Us...>
operator+( pack<Ts...>, pack<Us...> )
{ return {}; }

constexpr auto Classes = pack_v<>
#ifdef USE_A
  +pack_v<A>
#endif
#ifdef USE_B
  +pack_v<B>
#endif
#ifdef USE_C
  +pack_v<C>
#endif
;
using ClassList = decltype(Classes);
```

in which we add together type packs to get our answer.

In C++11, replace `pack_v<?>` with `pack<?>{}`.

Comment: Indeed, easier to drop first type than last one.

Comment: That is a very extensive answer to my rather stupid question. Could have seen that trick myself… thanks a lot! (Also to the two other respondents)

Answer (score 5):

How about something like:

```
using ClassList = pack<
#if defined(USE_A) 
    A,
#endif
#if defined (USE_B)
    B,
#endif
#if defined (USE_C)
    C,
#endif
    struct dummy // For comma
>;
```

And then provide an helper class to drop last element.

Answer (score 2):

Just add them one after the other

```
using ClassList = pack<void
#ifdef USE_A
                      ,A
#endif
#ifdef USE_B
                      ,B
#endif
#ifdef USE_C
                      ,C
#endif
                        >;
```

The `void` is necessary so that the comma works with the first non-void parameter. There are two ways to deal with this first `void` element. Either amend your `do_something` to do nothing for `T=void` or remove it using a helper `template` as explained in [Yakk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44674690/1023390).